# What software can I use to poll my audience during presentation?

Tags: presentation

I recently attended a lecture where the speaker used piece of software to interactively poll the audience and display the results. The particular solution was [ResponseWare](https://www.turningtechnologies.com/response-solutions/responseware). What other solutions are available? Worth the money (if paid)? Pros and cons?

Please note, that I'm not interested in top 5 results of Google search.. I'd be more interested to hear personal experiences with specific software, both as a presenter or audience.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software recommendations, and should be migrated accordingly.

Comment: Even if it's not off-topic, Stack Exchanges generally frown upon "shopping list" or "recommendation list" type questions.

Comment: [Software questions are not inherently off-topic at Academia.SE](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/175/11365)

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, what can the software provide that a show of hands can't?

Answer (score 6):

The [Software Carpentry](http://software-carpentry.org) instructors do lots of presentations where they need/expect rapid, interactive feedback. They (especially Greg Wilson) have lots of experience of different ways of doing this. Note that [their current method, that works extremely well, is to use different coloured sticky notes](http://software-carpentry.org/workshops/operations.html#feedback).

I haven't seen a technical solution that worked better; most are considerably worse. However, this is only practical for yes/no or multiple choice polls.

Comment: Thanks - interesting to see low-tech solution from high-tech shop! =)

Answer (score 2):

The organizers of a workshop I recently attended used [Socrative](http://socrative.com/) to help drive discussion by letting attendees choose among topics that had been introduced during the first half of the session. I found it pretty effective, and since it is HTML5/JS driven, it doesn't need an app or download. You can access the site from any Internet-enabled device and watch the answers come in in real time.

Comment: Thank - I'm leaning particularly towards no-app solutions and Socrative looks good indeed.